# Galaxy s3 not charging while connecting to Arduino mega ADK

Tags: android, arduino, samsung-mobile, adk

i have an Ardunio mega ADK R3 and Samsung Galaxy S3 , i'am trying to control the LED at pin 13 using an application on galaxy using this tutorial:

http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/

I've uploaded the Ardunio sketch , installed the application on galaxy , but when i connecting the galaxy to the Ardunio nothing happens and i'm not promoted to open the application on the galaxy , it's not even charging the phone ?

my question , if the phone not charging by Ardunio does it mean that there is a problem on the Ardunio board or this is an ordinary since the application on the phone not started?

i other words , if i connected the ardunio to the computer and then connected the galaxy to the ardunio without uploading or installing any sketch or application to android or ardunio and the galaxy not started to charge does this mean that there is a problem on the ardunio board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the Ardunio ADK with Google Nexuses and the Ardunio works fine without any problem ,so there is no problem in the Ardunio board ,but after referring to **"Beginning Arduino Programming"** page 51>>

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Arduino-Programming-Apress/dp/1430237775](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430237775)

""
**If you are experiencing that
nothing happens after you connected your device**, check if your filter matches the values you defined in
the Arduino sketch. **Another error source is that your board can’t deliver enough power to power the
Android device properly. As this is a requirement for the Open Accessory standard, make sure to power
the board with an external power source, if necessary.**
"""

so it's seems that the Galaxy S3 consume a lot of power and Ardunio can't deliver enough power to it.

Comment: I've added a 9v (6XAA) batteries to the ardunio and the galaxy s3 works is recognized by ardunio mega adk